# Finding eigenvector corresponding to smallest eigenvalue

Tags: matlab

I want to find the corresponding eigenvector of the eigenvalue of minimum magnitude of a matrix U. What is the easiest way to do this?

Currently I am using the algorithm

```
[evecs, D] = eigs(U);
evals = diag(D);
smallesteig = inf;
for k = 1:length(evals)
    if (evals(k) < smallesteig)
        smallesteig = evals(k);
        vec = evecs(:, k);
    end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very simple shorthand for this: `[V,D] = eigs(U,1,'SM')`.

If you look at the `eigs` documentation, it states:

```
EIGS(A,K,SIGMA) and EIGS(A,B,K,SIGMA) return K eigenvalues. If SIGMA is:
   'LM' or 'SM' - Largest or Smallest Magnitude
For real symmetric problems, SIGMA may also be:
   'LA' or 'SA' - Largest or Smallest Algebraic
   'BE' - Both Ends, one more from high end if K is odd
For nonsymmetric or complex problems, SIGMA may also be:
   'LR' or 'SR' - Largest or Smallest Real part
   'LI' or 'SI' - Largest or Smallest Imaginary part
```

So, `[V,D] = eigs(U,1,'SM')` returns the eigenvector and value for the **1**st eigenvalue of U when sorted by **S**mallest **M**agnitude.